# Is there any way to auto update a table field in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm wondering if there is any way to auto update a field at a given point of time, let's say at every day midnight update a given field.

assuming we have a table test

```sql
test(
days int not null
)
```

Is it possible to use a trigger function to automatically update days by adding 1 at midnight?

Comment: Review the concept of an ```EVENT```

Comment: You can also run a cron job. What I like about cron jobs is that they can be easily managed by Operations for production databases.